# Change Master Password from Unknown in Firefox

Tags: firefox, password-management

So, it seems I've somehow forgotten my Master Password for Firefox.  Stranger still, Firefox is actually prompting me for the password on startup for some unknown reason.

To troubleshoot why Firefox wants my Master Password on startup all of a sudden, I figured I'd check my list of stored passwords to see which one it might possibly be wanting.  But of course, without the correct Master Password, I can't do this.

Fortunately for me, there's very few passwords I'd actually had stored in Firefox.  So, if I could do a blind reset of the Master Password - that is, change the Master Password without knowledge of the previous one, with the understanding that all data protected by the previous password would be lost - it wouldn't be a big issue.  But, alas, I've not found a built-in way to do this.

Is there a way I can wipe out the password store, so that I can set a new Master Password and manually re-build the database, without having to un/re-install Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter `chrome://pippki/content/resetpassword.xul` into the Location Bar and press enter - found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  But now, I've still got the original problem to troubleshoot... why is Firefox prompting me for my Master Password on startup?  New question coming...

Comment: @lszi, do you have activated the firefox syncing? i think syncing needs the master password.

Comment: I don't use Firefox synching.  New thread is here:  http://superuser.com/questions/342493/change-master-password-from-unknown-in-firefox